# I have a problem binding event to AJAX populated list item. I want to be able to open a form and fill in its fields based on the list item values

Tags: html, angularjs, json, ajax, post

I am building a data entry application where we have two forms. Here is my code, where the list items get displayed in an unordered list. And on clicking on the list item a new form should populate with respective entries in each of the text boxes in the new form which are taken from the selected list item.

This is the code for the list items that are sent into the original form

```
include_once("test1.php");

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata, true);

$search= $request['search'];
$searchLabel= $request['searchItem'];

$newConnect= new connect();
$newConnect->dataform($search, $searchLabel);
class connect
{
    public function dataform($search, $searchLabel)
    {

    $test= new db_test1();
    $test->build_search($search, $searchLabel);
   $i = 1;
   while ($test->build_fetch(3))
   {
      $test_array = array();

      $test_array[0] = $test->src->PersonID;
      $test_array[1] = $test->src->LastName;
      $test_array[2] = $test->src->FirstName;


        foreach ($test_array as $ele)
        {
          $stmt .= <<<HTML
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 33%; padding: 20px;" >$ele</div>
HTML;
}

    echo <<<HTML
<li  tabindex="$i" id="listSelect" data-ng-model="model.$test_array[0]" 
data-ng-dbl-click="showForm()" class="list-group-item" style="li">$stmt</li>
HTML;

    $i++;

     }

  }
}
```

and the html part in orginal form file which is going to receive the list items into a unordered list by ng-bind html as a response from the above code

```
<div class="panel-body" data-ng-show="searchForm.\$submitted">

    <button class="btn btn-success text-right" data-ng- 
    click="showForm()">EDIT</button>

    <ul class="list-group" data-ng-bind-html="templateURLSearch">
    </ul>
</div>
```

controller of the application

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('myCtrlSearch', function ($scope, $http , $sce) {
         $scope.runSearch = function () {


        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'Connect-test1.php',
            data: {
                search: $scope.search,
                searchItem: $scope.searchItem
            },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.templateURLSearch= $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data);
        })
    };
});
```

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are having?

Comment: Why are you specifying content type `application/x-www-form-url-encoded` when you are JSON decoding the data? AngularJS automatic sets the content type to `application/json`. Why are you overriding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem receiving the list elements as html and bind event to them to manage in the controller. 
I found an alternate solution by instead of sending html as response, I sent values as response and filled into the existing html in the form.

```
include_once("test1.php");

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata, true);

$search= $request['search'];
$searchLabel= $request['searchItem'];

$newConnect= new connect();
$newConnect->dataform($search, $searchLabel);



class connect
{
  public function dataform($search, $searchLabel)
  {

    $test= new db_test1();
    $test->build_search($search, $searchLabel);
    $test_array = array();
         $i = 0;
         while ($test->build_fetch(3))
        {
             $test_array[$i]['ID'] = trim($test->src->PersonID, '""');
             $test_array[$i]['lastname'] = $test->src->LastName;
             $test_array[$i]['firstname'] = $test->src->FirstName;

                $i++;
        }

     $json= json_encode($test_array);
         echo $json;
  }
}
```

I changed the the html to this

```
<div class="panel-body" data-ng-show="searchForm.\$submitted" style="background- 
color: #F0F8FF;">

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li  data-ng-repeat="row in rows track by \$index">

            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 25%; padding: 20px;" > 
{{row.ID}}</div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 25%; padding: 20px;" > 
{{row.lastname}}</div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 25%; padding: 20px;" > 
{{row.firstname}}</div>

                <button class="btn btn-success text-right" data-ng- 
click="showFilled(row)">EDIT</button>

        </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```